# Thermal pad with a via: how to deal with solder paste?

Tags: pcb-design, via, solder-paste, qfn

I have a [TLC59283RGET](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59283.pdf) part which comes in a [VQFN24](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/mpqf124g/mpqf124g.pdf) housing.

It has a thermal pad on the bottom.

In my schematic, I have placed a via on that thermal pad, so I can route it as GND to other places.

I am worried about the solder paste though. Looking at my solder paste layer, I see that the fabrication process will apply paste to the via.

Would that cause issues?

Do I need to adjust my solder-paste mask when I add a via to a thermal pad?

Currently, this is the via, labeled 'GND':

[image]

And this is the solder paste mask:

[image]

Note that the solder-mask is shown in purple. The paste mask in grey. I use EasyEDA for designing the PCB.

The way I read that, is that the paste will be applied in the hole of the via?

(On the other side of the PCB, I have the exact same part, btw. With the intention of coupling their grounds and thermal pads.)

Comment: I put vias under the thermal pads, stitching vias. Solder paste goes only where paste mask is open, where part will be soldered. I do not open paste mask on via pads. One thing, I sometimes regret having a mirrored part placed right other opposite side, while looking at the Gerber file.

Comment: Are pages 26, "EXAMPLE BOARD LAYOUT", and 27, "EXAMPLE STENCIL DESIGN", of the datasheet you linked to of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pastemask checkerboard pattern to apply paste on the square, with the pattern covering your via in the middle. Then you shouldn't have a problem with wicking into the via as long as it's surrounded by soldermask (you will need to add this to your padstack.)

More here: https://www.pcblibraries.com/forum/ipc7093a-btc-qfn-solder-mask-defined-thermal-pad_topic2154.html

You can also cap the via, at some extra cost.